# Is there a why to call functions from functions more than once?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get functions to work across multiple files,
seems i can get test1 to call test2 and test 2 to call test3 (running separately).
but test2 cannot call test3 (if test2 was called by test1)

I have tried a couple of different ways of doing this and get either "Undefined" or the below,
So I'm obviously missing something fundamental.

Can anyone shed some light, Please.

Current output:

```
TEST 1 - Calling test2
TEST 2 - Calling test3
C:\***\test2.js:6
    lib.test3()
        ^

TypeError: lib.test3 is not a function
```

Expected Output:

```
TEST 1 - Calling test2
TEST 2 - Calling test3
Hello test 3
```

index.js

```
module.exports = {
    test1: require('./test1'),
    test2: require('./test2'),
    test3: require('./test3'),
};
```

test1.js

```
const lib = require('./index')
function test1() {
    console.log('TEST 1 - Calling test2')
    lib.test2()
}

test1();

module.exports = test1;
```

test2.js

```
const lib = require('./index')
function test2() {
    console.log('TEST 2 - Calling test3')
    lib.test3()
};

module.exports = test2;
```

test3.js

```
const lib = require('./index')
function test3() {
    console.log("Hello test 3")
}

module.exports = test3;
```

Comment: One possibility is there's a circular reference here, as in `test3.js` requires `index.js` which requires `test3.js` and things get messed up. If you can avoid that, and instead have each file directly import *exactly* what it needs from the other file, like `test2.js` requires `./test3`, you might resolve it.

Comment: There is indeed a circular `require()` which will cause unpredictable and poor results.  you have `index.js` requires `test1`, `test2` and `test3`, but each of those three modules requires `index`.  So, that's circular.  Can't do that.  I'm surprised that any of them work, but you have to remove the circular reference, usually by breaking common things out into it's own module that everything else can include without causing circular references.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, resolved the circular referencing, and its working now.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, resolved the circular referencing, and its working now.

Comment: you can use dynamic require (require inside function) if you are aware of how it'll impact the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a circular `require()` which will cause unpredictable and poor results. You have `index.js` requires `test1`, `test2` and `test3`, but each of those three modules requires `index`. So, that's circular. Can't do that.

I'm surprised that any of them work, but you have to remove the circular reference, usually by breaking common things out into its own module that everything else can include without causing circular references.